# Multiple on change listeners (Android Preferences)

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have  a common listener for all my ListPreferences. But a few ListPreferences are special and I would like to add another onPreferenceChangeListener to it. But I'm not sure how to do this the proper way, since there is no addOnPreferenceChangeListener only setOnPreferenceChangeListener.

Any recommendations?

PS. Why is there no add variant?

Comment: You could implement your own custom PreferenceChangeListener, and use that set method to use it.

Comment: I also want to call the default one, is there some way to trigger it or should I copy that code to my special listener?

Comment: I think you can avoid code duplication. Not sure how though.